# On enter key pressed, submit input and move to another item

Tags: java, javafx, keyboard

On enter key pressed, how to submit input and move to another item, e.g. `TextField`, `DatePicker`, `Button` etc.?

Comment: You can use node.requestfocus()

Comment: @user55924 Thanks for that method

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188); including a [mcve] will guide future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `onAction` event handler and call `requestFocus(...)` to focus the next control when the user commits an action:

```
@FXML TextField fName;
@FXML TextField lName;
@FXML DatePicker birthDay;
@FXML TextField address;
@FXML TextField city;
@FXML TextField telephoneNmbr;
@FXML TextField email;
@FXML Button closeBtn;
@FXML Button okBtn;

public void initialize(){

    fName.setOnAction(e -> lName.requestFocus());
    lName.setOnAction(e -> birthDay.requestFocus());
    birthDay.setOnAction(e -> address.requestFocus());

    // etc...

    okBtn.setOnAction(e -> {
        // whatever you need to do when OK is pressed...
    });
}
```

You could potentially reduce the amount of code if you need:

```
Control[] focusOrder = new Control[] {
    fName, lName, birthDay, address, city, 
    telephoneNmbr, email, closeBtn, okBtn};

for (int i = 0 ; i < focusOrder-1 ; i++) {
    Control nextControl = focusOrder[i+1];
    focusOrder[i].addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, e -> nextControl.requestFocus());
}

okBtn.setOnAction(...);
```

Note that the space bar is usually associated with triggering an action on a button if the button has keyboard focus. You can make the button the "default button" which will change its appearance and make it respond (semi-globally) to the enter key.

Answer (score 0):

I have `Stage` which consists of the following items. This is how I did it:

```
@FXML TextField fName;
@FXML TextField lName;
@FXML DatePicker birthDay;
@FXML TextField address;
@FXML TextField city;
@FXML TextField telephoneNmbr;
@FXML TextField email;
@FXML Button closeBtn;
@FXML Button okBtn;

public void initialize(){
//ENTER key pressed -> focus on next item
        fName.setOnKeyPressed((KeyEvent event) ->{ switch (event.getCode()){
            case ENTER:lName.requestFocus();}});
        lName.setOnKeyPressed((KeyEvent event) ->{ switch (event.getCode()){
            case ENTER:birthDay.requestFocus();}});
        birthDay.setOnKeyPressed((KeyEvent event) ->{ switch (event.getCode()){
            case ENTER:address.requestFocus();}});
        address.setOnKeyPressed((KeyEvent event) ->{ switch (event.getCode()){
            case ENTER:city.requestFocus();}});
        city.setOnKeyPressed((KeyEvent event) ->{ switch (event.getCode()){
            case ENTER:telephoneNmbr.requestFocus();}});
        telephoneNmbr.setOnKeyPressed((KeyEvent event) ->{ switch (event.getCode()){
            case ENTER:email.requestFocus();}});
        email.setOnKeyPressed((KeyEvent event) ->{ switch (event.getCode()){
            case ENTER:okBtn.requestFocus();}});

        //ENTER key pressed on okBtn-> Save info
        okBtn.setOnKeyPressed((KeyEvent event) ->{ switch (event.getCode()){
            case ENTER:try {okDugmeKlik(); /*method for saving data into database*/} catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}}});

}
```

Comment: Why are you using `setOnKeyPressed` instead of `setOnAction`?

Comment: Because it works, don't know much theory behind it (new to JavaFX), what is difference?

Comment: You wouldn't have to test for which key is pressed, since actions are fired when the user presses enter in a text field.